# How to prevent page scroll when pasting?

Tags: handsontable

When pasting data into a cell, the page scrolls to the top of the page or to the bottom of the targeted cell.

How can I remove any scrolling on paste? I would like for the page to not move at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply fixes like below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var position_Y_before = null;

    $(".handsontable").handsontable({
        //some code here for initializing the table and its functions

        //Then I added this callback function
        beforeKeyDown: function(e) {
            position_Y_before = window.pageYOffset || 0;
        };

    });

    //Here we prevent from scrolling to top of page after pasting to handsontable with cmd+v or ctrl+v
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(position_Y_before != null){
            window.scrollTo(0, position_Y_before);
            position_Y_before = null;
        }
    });

});
```

This works for me at least, hope it helps you as well!